# Angular JS $http Json parsing issues

Tags: angularjs, http, response

All,

I have this JSon object as my response (object containing an array of objects)

here is what I see when I call using the web browser

```
{"skillAndAvgCTList":[{"skill":"Notion Count","avgCT":"22.0"},{"skill":"Tube Count","avgCT":"24.0"},{"skill":"2nd Count","avgCT":"26.0"},{"skill":"Shelf Count","avgCT":"20.0"}]}
```

But when I do this

```
 $http.get("http://localhost:8080/fwms-unknown/svc/usermanage/userManagement").then(function (resp) {
                    console.log('Success', resp.data);




                    this.skillsAndAvgCT = resp.data.skillAndAvgCTList;
                  alert('this.skillsAndAvgCT'+ this.skillsAndAvgCT);
```

the alert window shows:

```
this.skillsAndAvgCT[object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object].
```

I want to use ng-repeat and read 'skill' and 'avgCT'.

How can I do this? I think somehow I making mistakes getting the response data into the variable.

Comment: you definitely make mistakes by debugging with `alert`. Use `console` instead

Comment: Is `this.skillsAndAvgCT[0].skill` working?

Comment: Do a `console.log()` instead of an `alert()` and check in your browser console the values. [F12 for Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) and [Ctrl+Shift+J or Cmd+Shift+J](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick responses. I used console.log('resp.data.skillAndAvgCTList[0].skill'+ resp.data.skillAndAvgCTList[0].skill);  and it printed the value. Now if I want to use skillAndAvgCTList in ng-repeat, how should I go about? sorry newbee troubles.

Answer (score 0):

So skillAndAvgCTList is your key. You could do this to display them [Working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dovVVR)
Just store Data in data2 with the key skillAndAvgCTList (look at codepen) :

```
 <ion-content>
  <div ng-repeat="d in data2">{{d.skill}}<div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.skillsAndAvgCT` should not be inside quotes.

This:

```
alert(this.skillsAndAvgCT);
```

Should give you the same as:

```
{"skillAndAvgCTList":[{"skill":"Notion Count","avgCT":"22.0"},{"skill":"Tube Count","avgCT":"24.0"},{"skill":"2nd Count","avgCT":"26.0"},{"skill":"Shelf Count","avgCT":"20.0"}]}
```

Run through it like this in js:

```
for(i = 0; i < this.skillsAvgCT.length; i++)
{
    alert(this.skillsAvgCT[i].skill + " " + this.skillsAvgCT[i].avgCT);
}
```

For Angular, add this.SkillsAvgCT to $scope, and then do ng-repeat in your html.

```
$scope.skillsAvgCT = this.skillsAvgCT;
```

HTML (in table):

`<tr ng-repeat="s in skillsAvgCT"><td>{{s.skill}}</td></tr>`

Answer (score 0):

The data which you are getting from server is correct and you stored it correctly.Just make change in javascripts code as given below

```
this.skillsAndAvgCT = resp.data;
```

Then to show data of object on your respective view use following code snippet

```
      <ol>
         <li ng-repeat="item in skillsAndAvgCT">
           <span> skills:{{item.skill}}|AvgCT:{{item.avgCT}}</span>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: I did this and it is printing {{item.skill}} and {{item.avgCT}} as is. so basically ng-repeat not getting the values? or my $scope.skillAndAvgCTList is not getting the values?

Comment: and also you said this.skillsAndAvgCT = resp.data; but I did this.skillsAndAvgCT = resp.data.skillsAndAvgCTList; is n't it correct?

Comment: if its printing {{item.avgCT}} and {{item.skill}} then check if angular is working for ur applications or not.Because if item.skills is empty then angular will show nothing only blank.Check console of browser for any error related to angular.

Comment: the way you stored data inside object is also correct I only suggested different flavour of it.Do One thing on your html view add {{5+6}} this statement and run your application if it prints "11" then your angular is working but if it prints {{5+6}} it means angular is not working.Its just basic way to test angular .

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your time and help. I tried <td>{{5+6}} </td> without having any ng-repeat in <tr>. It worked fine. It printed 11 as expected. But when I add <tr ng-repeat ="item in cntrl.skillAndAvgCTList" >, it is not even printing 11. I think the control is not even passing beyond <tr ng-repeat ..> ..what you think causing this? thanks.

Comment: hey, it worked. All I did is removed cntrl from cntrl.skillAndAvgCTList. it is weird but it works now. thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score -1):

ng-repeat really belongs in the html vs your Javascript.

```
<div ng-repeat="model in skillsAndAvgCT">
    {{model.skill}} - {{model.avgCT}}
</div>
```

Or just use your standard Javascript skills to iterate through the list of

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
for (var prop in obj) {
   alert("o." + prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
}
```

Comment: I added it in the html <tr ng-repeat="model in cntrl.skillAndAvgCTList">
        <td>{{model.skill}}</td>
        <td>{{model.avgCT}}</td>
    </tr> but it is just printing {{model.skill}} and {{model.avgCT}} in the row without printing actual values.

Comment: It sounds like a scope issue. Check out this example http://jsfiddle.net/84q86rx2/